# Why this query using union all is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT a.status, count(a.status) FROM
(SELECT 'Delivered' AS status
UNION ALL SELECT 'Buffered'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Not Delivered'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Not Reported') a
LEFT JOIN 
bulk_sms_numbers
ON a.status = bulk_sms_numbers.delivery_status
WHERE bulk_sms_id = 52
GROUP BY a.status;
```

and the following result:

```
+-----------+-----------------+
|  status   | count(a.status) |
+-----------+-----------------+
| Buffered  |              10 |
| Delivered |            3200 |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

I want the resultset to contain all the possibles statuses listed in the union all query

Example output of what I need.

```
+---------------+-----------------+
|    status     | count(a.status) |
+---------------+-----------------+
| Buffered      |              10 |
| Delivered     |            3200 |
| Not Delieverd |               0 |
| Not Reported  |               0 |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

I'm using MySql

Comment: The `WHERE bulk_sms_id = 52` is the likely culprit...

Answer (score 5):

move the condition from the `WHERE` clause into `ON` so the filtering will takes place while joining and not on the final result list.

```
SELECT a.status, count(a.status) 
FROM
    (
        SELECT 'Delivered' AS status
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Buffered'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Not Delivered'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'Not Reported'
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN bulk_sms_numbers
        ON a.status = bulk_sms_numbers.delivery_status AND 
            bulk_sms_id = 52
GROUP BY a.status;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87b1c/5)

Comment: +1 for winning a three way race by seconds for identical answers.

Comment: It counts one for the values not present in `bulk_sms_numbers` I need it to count 0

Comment: first, where is the column `bulk_sms_id` located? second, are you using `COUNT(*)`? did you see ny fiddle demo?

Comment: Not the only change to my original query was to change the WHERE for the AND. `bulk_sms_id` is in `bulk_sms_numbers` table. The `delivery_status` column contains some null values, I don't know if this cause a problem

Comment: can you give sample records containing `NULL` values so we can find solution on it.

Comment: @Cesar in you example, `Buffered` is also `NULL` right? so it will still be recorded as 'Not reported'?

Comment: I would like to accomplish the following, count all null values as 'Not reported', count all not existing values as 0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23983/discussion-between-jw-and-cesar)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the WHERE condition into the ON clause and using an OUTER join.

```
SELECT a.status, count(a.status) FROM
(SELECT 'Delivered' AS status
UNION ALL SELECT 'Buffered'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Not Delivered'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Not Reported') a
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
bulk_sms_numbers
ON a.status = bulk_sms_numbers.delivery_status
AND bulk_sms_id = 52
GROUP BY a.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also giving column names to all and changing the `ON` to be conditional

```
SELECT a.status, count(a.status) FROM
(SELECT 'Delivered' AS status
UNION ALL SELECT 'Buffered' As status
UNION ALL SELECT 'Not Delivered' as status
UNION ALL SELECT 'Not Reported' as status) a
LEFT JOIN 
bulk_sms_numbers
ON a.status = bulk_sms_numbers.delivery_status
AND bulk_sms_id = 52
GROUP BY a.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a query like this:

```
SELECT cnt, IFNULL(delivery_status, 'Not Reported') delivery_status FROM (
    SELECT delivery_status, count(delivery_status) cnt FROM bulk_sms_numbers WHERE bulk_sms_id = 52 GROUP BY delivery_status
) x
```

and then in php I set default values for all statuses to 0

```
$data = $db->fetchAll($q, array($aid, $reference));

$statuses = array(
    'Buffered' => 0,
    'Delivered' => 0,
    'Not Delivered' => 0,
    'Not Reported' => 0,
);

foreach ($data as $value) {
    $statuses[$value['delivery_status']] = $value['cnt'];
}
```

Althought this resolves my problem, is not an answer to my question.
I would like to find a pure sql answer.